# How to distinguish between Post "Like" Links and Comment "Like" Links on Facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, inheritance, hierarchy

A like link in Facebook can be accessed with `document.getElementsByClassName("UFILikeLink")[i]` for some integer i. If you're to iterate through that entire list of elements, though, you get *any* kind of Like link -- regular posts, or comments in a post. What I'm wondering is, how can you distinguish between a "comment" like and a "post" like? I am assuming it has something to do with class hierarchy (checking whether the link is within some sort of Post class or not) but I'm not sure where to go beyond that.

Comment: please post your html so we can work out a solution if possible.

Comment: I currently don't have any html. In general, I'd just like to know how to access post-specific links, rather than an entire list of like links. Rather than searching through the document I'm thinking 

`document.getElementByClassName("PostClass").getElementsByClassName("UFILikeLink")[1]`

Would that make sense? PostClass is a dummy class name since I don't know what FB actually calls them. 

Sorry, I have very little JS experience.